Drives visibility in file explorer when GParted is open
Under linux Mint 21, the default file manager is Nemo.
On Nemo side bar, you have a list of available drive, and they mount if you click on them.
Now, if I open GParted, all the unmounted drives disappear from this side bar except one (for which I have selected non-default mount options in gnome-disk-utility)
What is the mechanism at play here, that changes the visibility of drives in Nemo when I open GParted?

Here's what I think, but can't find any evidence for it in the documentary:
GParted automatically unmounts your drives to prevent data loss or corruption. As long as a drive is mounted, the system can access, read and write to it. If you were to make changes to the partition table, for example, data may be lost or changed. This is why GParted unmounts the drives.
Once a drive is unmounted, it is no longer available to the file system and is therefore not displayed in Nemo.

I also use LinuxMint myself and have already observed this behavior. However, I feel that only some drives are ejected. (e.g. USB sticks, external hard disks, etc.) I can imagine that it depends on how exactly the drives are mounted (i.e. via which option in /etc/fstab and under which path in the file system)
However, I can't verify this at the moment as I don't have access to my PC.
It is also possible that I am completely wrong and other people here have more knowledge.

I'm not sure this is related to mounting or unmounting: from what I see, mounted drive are never ejected. Unmounted drive however, are not visible ("discovered"?) anymore.
